# Update ID using two or more Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I Have a table called UID and the data looks like:

```
U_ID   Urgent  Impact  Severe  Priority
1      1       1       NULL    1
2      1       2       NULL    1
3      1       3       NULL    1
4      3       4       NULL    3
5      2       2       NULL    2
6      NULL    NULL    1       NULL
7      NULL    NULL    NULL    1
8      NULL    NULL    NULL    2
9      NULL    NULL    NULL    3
10     NULL    NULL    NULL    4
11     1       NULL    NULL    NULL
12     1       1       NULL    NULL
13     1       2       NULL    NULL
14     1       2       1       NULL
15     1       3       1       NULL
```

and also I have another table called STID and the data looks like:

```
Priority    Impact  Urgent   ID
    3            4  3        1
    3            4  3        1
    2            2  2        1
    2            2  2        1
    2            2  2        1
```

and Also I have another table called PRID and the data looks like:

```
Priority   ID
1          2
2          2
2          2
3          2
4          2
```

I Have a Table called FID and it contains  U_ID and ID columns So I am trying to Insert those columns using the U_ID from UID Table  and ID from STID and PRID Table.How can I do this?

My Final FID Table should like this:

```
U_ID   ID
4      1
4      1
5      1
5      1
5      1
7      2
8      2
8      2
9      2
10     2
```

Comment: What about adding more meaningfull names? Would be a lot easier to follow what your trying to do.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want duplicated records to appear in the final FID table and yeah walking through this is daunting with naming being almost identical for all the tables.  What is the PK on the table at that point or are there other columns?  Anyway, I agree with previous comments, please consider easier to follow example.

Comment: @NGM I want duplicated records in the Final Table. There are no other columns. I have changed the naming

Comment: @NGM The U_ID in the UID Table is an Identity Column

Comment: @Sam: Can columns in `STID` and `PRID` contain NULLs?

Comment: @Andriy Yes they can have Nulls

Answer (score 0):

```
select U_ID, S.ID
from UID as U
  inner join STID as S
    on S.Pr = U.PR and
       S.Im = U.IM and
       S.Ur = U.UR
union all
select U_ID, P.ID
from UID as U
  inner join PRID as P
    on U.PR = P.PR and
       U.IM is null and
       U.UR is null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select u.U_ID, s.ID
into #temp
from UID as u
  inner join STID as s on (u.Priority=s.Priority and u.Impact=s.Impact)
and s.Priority is not null

insert into #temp
select u.U_ID, p.ID
from UID as u
  inner join PRID as p on (u.Priority=p.Priority)
and u.U_ID not in (select U_ID from #temp)

Select * from #temp
order by U_ID

Drop Table #Temp
```